# What's the path to save a video in iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, video

I'm saving a video on  my iPad with this code on swift:

```
  let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

        let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String

        var filePath:String? = nil
        var fileNamePostfix = 0
        do {
            filePath =
            "\(documentsDirectory)/\(dateTimePrefix)-\(fileNamePostfix++).mp4"
        } while (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath))
    let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    self.fileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL( fileUrl , recordingDelegate: delegate)
```

But I can't see if my video is saving because I can't open path var/mobile/media...

There are any form to save pictures on photos folder?

Thanks!!

Comment: What's the full error you are getting?

Comment: Does this work in the simulator?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but I can't see if really my video is saving on any path... I tried its on device (iPad) in the simulator I can't simulate a camera

Comment: Oh, if that's all you want then just open the app container in the devices window of Xcode. Then you can see what is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to see if the files are getting into the documents folder on your device then you can see the container in the Devices window of Xcode 6.

Just **Window > Devices** then select your device. Then select your app, click the gear button and tell it if you want to view, download, or replace the container for the app.

[image]

Note that you can also save the videos into the Saved Photos album, assuming they are in the right format. Check out this method in the ALAssetsLibrary Class:

```
writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock:
```

Comment: I can see this while I'm saving with: self.fileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL( fileUrl , recordingDelegate: delegate)  But if I want save this in photos folder iPad with: writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum How can I use this??

Comment: i tried with UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath, self, nil, nil)  But don't get save this

Answer (score 1):

You can't save assets to the Media Library — the stuff that appears in the Music, Videos, and Podcasts apps. The only way to get things into there is by syncing from iTunes on the desktop or downloading from the iTunes Store.

If you want to save a video so that it appears in the Photos app, use the [Photos framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408) in iOS 8:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(url)
}, completionHandler: { success, error in
    if !success { NSLog("Failed to create video: %@", error) }
})
```

(In iOS 7 and earlier, use the AssetsLibrary framework instead.)

Comment: I'm getting error: dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/PhotosUI.framework/PhotosUI     Reason: image not found.  I imported Photos framework...

Comment: Are you getting the error on device? In the simulator?

Answer (score -1):

You can't access the photo system folder directly. However if you just want to see the files you've saved, you don't have to. Just enable document sharing by adding UIFileSharingEnabled to your Info.plist.

When you plug your device in and open iTunes, it will show your documents folder like so:

[image]

More info on filesharing [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app).

Comment: You can always add the recorded video from its location on disk to the Photo Library.